# Android/Java: How to disable auto-scroll when RecyclerView visibility goes from GONE to VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I set `RecyclerView` in XML file as gone as you can see in the codes.

After get updates from server I want to show them when I set `RecyclerView` visibility from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`
it will scroll down all the page to reach this `RecyclerView`.

How I can fix this issue or this there any better solution to use `ShimmerLayout` and ``RecyclerView``` without happening this.

This is part of my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        // Some rows are here
        // ...

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/news_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            // Another Row

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/latest_news_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/news_shimmer_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                    <include layout="@layout/shimmer_news_row" />

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set **GONE** when you launched activity
make it **VISBILE** by default.
then data load on recycler view it will not recycle

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by wrapping recyclerview with nestedscrollview.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_recycler_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```